# Query a part of XML and write to another variable along with common tag

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have an xml in below format

```
<maintag>
    <common1> 123 </common1>
    <common2> 234 </common>
    <part>
        <partid>1</partid>
        <partprice> 500 </partprice>
    </part>
    <part>
        <partid>1</partid> 
        <partprice> 500 </partprice> 
    </part>
</maintag>
```

my requirement is to select `partid` with id 1. also I need the tag `<common1>`, 
 `<common2`> which is common for both part in my result usin C#

Comment: Do you want to extract information from one or both of the elements with partid 1. Question is unclear.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve... What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Sins you did not specify fully what you wanted. I've made up an example.

(notice) that `<common2 >` element does not match with the closing type `< common>` this need to be `</common2 >`!!

**load file XDocument**

```
        XDocument _doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\t\\My File2.txt");
```

**Get common elements**

```
        string common1 = _doc.XPathSelectElement("maintag/common1").Value;
        string common2 = _doc.XPathSelectElement("maintag/common2").Value;
```

**Get all elements where part id == 1 and put them in a list**

```
        List<XElement> data = _doc.XPathSelectElements("maintag/part").Where(x => x.Element("partid").Value == 1.ToString()).ToList();

        // loop al elemements and extract results from previous query
        foreach (XElement row in data)
        {
            // Get value from partid element
            string id = row.Element("partid").Value;
            // Get value from partprice element
            string price = row.Element("partprice").Value;
        }
```

**Selects first element that matcht with id 1**

```
        XElement data2 = _doc.XPathSelectElements("maintag/part").Where(x => x.Element("partid").Value == 1.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        // Get value from partid element
        string id1 = data2.Element("partid").Value;
        // Get value from partprice element
        string price1 = data2.Element("partprice").Value;
```